# C# OracleCommandではOracleParameter SqlParameterどちらを使いますか？

Tags: c#

初歩的な質問ですみません。

OracleCommandでパラメータ設定する際に利用するパラメータクラスは
通常はOracleParameterと思いますが、SqlParameterというクラスもあるので、
何が違うのかわかりましたらご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlParameter`はMicrosoft SQL Server向けの`System.Data.SqlClient`専用のクラスです。`OracleCommand`では`OracleParameter`を使用してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Oracle Parameterを利用します。

Answer (score 2):

各`Command`クラスには`CreateParameter()`メソッドが用意されています。どのパラメータークラスを使うかに悩むようでしたら、こちらを利用したほうが確実です。なお

- [`OracleCommand.CreateParameter()`メソッド](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77579_01/win.121/e72575/OracleCommandClass.htm#i998335)は`OracleParameter`クラスインスタンスを返します。
- [`SqlCommand.CreateParameter()`メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.createparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)は`SqlParameter`クラスインスタンスを返します。

となっています。

これとは別に、ADO.NETは[ファクトリモデル](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cy5kfe3c(v=vs.110).aspx)が導入されています。このファクトリモデルで提供される`DbConnection`、`DbCommand`、`DbParameter`という抽象クラスを用いることで特定のデータベースエンジンに依存しないコーディングも可能です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
データベースに依存しないコーディングは魅力的ですね!

ただ、大量のデータをINSERTやUPDATEする際に
OracleCommand.ArrayBindCountでINSERTやUPDATE件数を
指定すると高速で動作するという話を聞いているため
まずはOracleCommandでの実装を進める予定です。

OracleCommand.CreateParameter()ではデフォルトの
OracleParameterが作成されるようですね。
OracleParameterのコンストラクタがたくさんあって、
型指定等をして各パラメータを設定していくのが
多少ですが面倒と思っています。

Comment: @mame さん、それだけでは答えようがないので必要であれば新規質問をしてください。

Comment: 何かあれば新規に質問いたします。